# Fortran fpm Run Tests on Module in Parent Directory

Tags: testing, fortran, gfortran

I have written a module in fortran that I want to test using [`fortran-fpm`](https://fpm.fortran-lang.org/en/index.html) and [`vegetables`](https://gitlab.com/everythingfunctional/vegetables).

My directory structure looks like this:

```
my_repo/
├─ foo/
│  ├─ bar/
│  │  ├─ my_module.f90
│  │  ├─ test/
│  │  │  ├─ main.f90
│  │  │  ├─ my_module_test.f90
├─ fpm.toml
```

When I run `fpm test`, I get this error:

```
<ERROR>*cmd_run*:targets error:Unable to find source for module dependency: "my_module" used by "foo/bar/test/my_module_test.f90"
STOP 1
```

If I instead move `my_module.f90` into the test directory, all the tests run fine. How do I point `my_module_test.f90` to `my_module.f90` without having my source code in the `test` directory?

---

I have tried:

1. Including:

```
[test-dependencies]
my_module = { path = "foo/bar/my_module.f90" }
```

in my `fpm.toml` file at the top of my repo as suggested in the [documentation](https://fpm.fortran-lang.org/en/spec/manifest.html#test-targets). It then prompts me to put another `fpm.toml` file at `foo/bar/`. When I do that, it still gives me the same error.

2. Using putting `file: "foo/bar/my_module.f90` at the top of `my_module_test.f90`. As suggested [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/program-structure/using-module-mod-files.html).

---

**EDIT:**
Note that my fpm.toml file looks like this:

```
name = "My_Project"
author = "NolantheNerd"

[install]
library = true

[library]
source-dir = "foo/bar"
include-dir = "foo/bar"

[build]
external-modules = "foo/bar"
link = "foo/bar/my_module.f90"

[dev-dependencies]
vegetables = { git = "https://gitlab.com/everythingfunctional/vegetables.git", tag = "v7.2.2" }

[[test]]
name = "TestsForMyModule"
source-dir = "foo/bar/test"
main = "main.f90"
link = "foo/bar/my_module.f90"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to [everythingfunctional](https://everythingfunctional.wordpress.com/), the creator of `vegetables` for his solution:

> Your build section is incorrect, and actually unnecessary in your case. Try removing it and let us know how it goes.

> Edit: just noticed as well that the link entry in your test section is incorrect and unnecessary as well.

See the thread [here](https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/running-tests-with-fpm/2758).